# Scfi/fantasy novel with archeology, ancient civilisation/aliens and possibly reincarnation themes?

Tags: story-identification, reincarnation, ancient-races

I've been looking for this novel for years, I first read it in the late 1990s as a paperback. It was a mid-length novel, at least 200 pages.

It was about an archaeologist who was excavating an ancient site, possibly a temple. It was a prehistoric site, older than recorded history and there was some lost civilisation and I believe ancient aliens (or at least non-humans, I can't remember if they were from another planet or not) themes. The civilisation was either a fictional undiscovered one or linked to a very early one, BCE, as in not related to anything dark ages or medieval era. Edited to add: I believe the temple or site that was being excavated was more advanced than any other site from the ancient world. I'm thinking more advanced architecturally or engineering wise, as in monumental, huge. I feel like it was set in north Africa or the area we call the Middle East, possibly Turkey or around that part of the world. However, I believe the archaeologists were either European, maybe British or North American.

The archaeologist also had two students who were working with him, a young man and woman, who were experiencing dreams or reincarnation type memories of the site. I seem to remember a scene where these students are feeling "drawn" to the ancient site and are worried that their memories or visions are mental illness or hallucinations.

I feel like it was set around the time it was published [1980s or 90s?] or the near future, i.e. it wasn't particularly futuristic.

I borrowed it from my local library so I think it must have been a mainstreamish publisher. I really can't remember if it was intended for YA audiences or not, I feel it could have been written for mid-teens to adult audiences. Also gotta say I don't remember it being wildly well written or original or anything like that, it was a pretty decent novel with some interesting elements, but that's about it. I don't know why I want to find it again so badly, it's just been bugging me for years :)

I asked about this on another site (librarything) so can rule out novels written by Andre Norton, Michael Crichton and Pat Murphy.

Any leads or ideas would be very much appreciated! Thanks for your time :)

Comment: What parts about it feel like science fiction/fantasy other than the lost civilisation bit and the dreams? Was there advanced ancient technology? Magic? I think that it probably does fit for our site, but those details would help distinguish it from others. Do you remember anything about the plot? Do things happen to these people?

Comment: I think the idea was that the civilisation who built the site which was discovered were either aliens from another planet or a non-human species from Earth? I'm afraid I don't remember if the character's dreams/memories are triggered by something technological or magic. It might have been a reincarnation style plot or it might have been more like telepathy or possession. I hope that helps a bit?

Comment: You have described a genre. Can you at least recall what part of the world this ancient civilization was located in? Mexico, Peru? Egypt, Anatolia, Mesopotamia?

Comment: That's true, my memories are not very specific. This question really got me thinking it may have been around the Middle East or north Africa. I am sure it wasn't anywhere in the southern hemisphere, so not Australia, I'm sure it wasn't North or South America. I don't think Europe (although Turkey could be a possibility) and not China or another Asian country. I will update my post to reflect this, thanks so much for your question, I should have narrowed that down myself but just didn't remember until asked :)

Comment: I guess there were no pyramids in the story? You would probably have remembered and mentioned if there were?

Comment: I think I would have remembered pyramids but there is a chance I read it long ago enough ago to have even blurred out that detail. There was something about big, monumental style architecture, so if you did think of one involving pyramids I'd definitely check it out. Argh, I know, pyramids are such a subgenre staple, that's probably 90% of them :)